React Native App Expo on iOS stops working as soon as it is opened
My application is being developed in react native using expo version 6.3.10 and SDK 51.0.7. Within the application I use the libraries below. The problem is that after building for development profile on IOS, it opens and then closes immediately. Without any logs in my console. Has anyone gone through something similar and managed to fix?
"dependencies": {
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.6.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.28",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.13",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "burgos-array": "^1.0.2",
    "burgos-documents": "^1.0.2",
    "burgos-estadosbrasil": "^1.0.1",
    "expo": "~51.0.7",
    "expo-av": "~14.0.5",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.14",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.5",
    "expo-image": "~1.12.9",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.5",
    "expo-keep-awake": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^13.0.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.28.2",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "^7.0.4",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-video-thumbnails": "~8.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-controlled-mentions": "^2.2.5",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-mask-text": "^0.14.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.2.4",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-number-format": "^5.3.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5",
    "uid": "^2.0.2",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
}

I couldn't find the real problem so I don't know where to start

the problem is probably with the custom fonts you're loading with "expo-font". Try using a native font and see if it keeps crashing.
